# JQuery UI: Если в кнопке нет текста, скрыть кнопку (внутри диалогового окна)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

У меня есть код:

```js
dialog_buttons_z = [{
    text: but1,
    click: function() {
      close_dialog();
      setTimeout(sp1 || emp, 1);
    }
  },
  {
    text: but2,
    click: function() {
      close_dialog();
      setTimeout(sp2 || emp, 1);
    }
  },
  {
    text: but3,
    click: function() {
      close_dialog();
      setTimeout(sp3 || emp, 1);
    }
  },
  {
    text: but4,
    click: function() {
      close_dialog();
      setTimeout(sp4 || emp, 1);
    }
  }
]
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Мне нужно сделать так, что если `but1`, `but2`, `but3` или `but4` были в значении `undefined`, `false`, или `''`, кнопки бы скрывались и не показывались.